# Angular Material Stepper custom icons ng-template has undefined context variable

Tags: angular, ng-template, mat-stepper, angular-material-11

I am trying to use an `ng-template` with the `matStepperIcon` property to override the default Angular Material's matStepper's icons. I also want to pass some data, and I tried using `ng-container` and `*ngTemplateOutlet`, however it only partially works.

As you can see from the following code, I would expect the `print` function to always print a defined value, however, after correctly printing the seven IDs of the steps it prints `undefined` seven times. Why is that and how do I prevent that from happening?

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let step of form.steps">
    <ng-template #ref let-step="id" matStepperIcon="edit">
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
      {{ print(step) }}
    </ng-template>
    
    <ng-template #ref let-step="id" matStepperIcon="number">
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
      {{ print(step) }}
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #ref let-step="id" matStepperIcon="done">
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
      {{ print(step) }}
    </ng-template>
    
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="ref; context: step"></ng-container>

    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>
        {{ step.id }}:
        {{ translateService.currentLang === "it" ? step.name : step.nameEn }}
      </ng-template>

      <!-- Step content-->
      </mat-step>
  </ng-container>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

[Link to StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bb3bhx?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Changing my code to the following, on the other hand, causes the `print` function to print all the correct IDs but it also prints the ID of the last step 8 times.

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let step of form.steps">
    <ng-template #ref matStepperIcon="edit">
      {{ print(step.id) }}
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #ref matStepperIcon="number">
      {{ print(step.id) }}
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #ref matStepperIcon="done">
      {{ print(step.id) }}
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="ref; context: step"></ng-container>

    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>
        {{ step.id }}:
        {{ translateService.currentLang === "it" ? step.name : step.nameEn }}
      </ng-template>

      <!-- Step content-->
    </mat-step>
  </ng-container>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use custom icons with MatStepper you should do several things:

- Teach library to take into account your set of icons.

We could disable `displayDefaultIndicatorType` like

```
providers: [{
   provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: {displayDefaultIndicatorType: false}
}]
```

But it won't help since Angular Material has predefined logic to show specific icon depending on internal step state https://github.com/angular/components/blob/28c36f8a02f72e51a4d6c6a797e2f913e5dede9b/src/cdk/stepper/stepper.ts#L442-L465

So, you can override base logic like here https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18307

```
@ViewChild(MatHorizontalStepper, { static: true }) stepper: MatHorizontalStepper;

ngOnInit() {
  this.stepper._getIndicatorType = (i, state) => state || 'number';
}
```

- Decide which icon to show depending on step

  ```
  <mat-step [state]="step.state">


  steps: [
    {
      id: 218,
      name: 'Dati richiedente',
      nameEn: 'Applicant data',
      state: 'home',
    },
    {
      id: 219,
      name: 'Richiesta Meeting',
      nameEn: 'Meeting request',
      state: 'edit'
    },
  ```
- Use built-in `matStepperIcon` context to access rendering `index`. With this index you can access corresponding `step`:

  ```
  <ng-template let-i="index" matStepperIcon="home">
    <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
    {{ print(form.steps[i]) }}
  </ng-template>
  ```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-17xvmo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it's happening but you can workaround by using bind method

```
<ng-template  #ref let-step="id" matStepperIcon="number">
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
      {{ print.bind(step) }}
</ng-template>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-66279259ng-template-has-undefined-context-variable?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is wrong, I didn't get how it should like, but found 3 mistake:

- You can't have 3 same template refs.
- Also you should define your templates outside ***ngFor** loop.
- And last - to provide some data to template, you should define it as an object with **$implicit** key.

[Here is stackblitz with changes](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jgkpry?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Your solution does not appear to be working, since it does not replace the default icons of the mat-stepper. The default icons are shown instead. The three `ng-template`s must go inside the `mat-horizontal-stepper` tag.